# Argparse - convenient way to have flag with neccessary and unecessary arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have a problem: I would like flag in my program to take two necessary arguments, and apart of it to have four options which are not necessary, and can be used with each other (eg. only options 1,2 and 4 turned on, only options 1 and 4 turned on etc.). I found the subargs option, but if I understand correctly, options in it are unique and you can only use one option for one run. Now I have the list with all options and I sort them and then split these list into 4 different, but it is non-convenient way (and I think non-professional). How can I solve this problem?

Example:

```
python3 main.py --make_it source target option1 itsargs option2 itsargs moreofitsargs option3 evenmoreargs option4 213 andevenmoreags
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @rdas done as an edit

Comment: Are the number of args fixed for each option?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no, every one should have its args in list

Comment: That sample will produce a `sys.argv[1:]` (what argparse uses) `['--make_it'. 'source', 'target', 'option1', ... 'andevenmoreags']`  How do you process those strings?  Where are the lists?  I see strings like 'andevenmoreargs',  Is that supposed to mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way (Posix conformant) is to use a prefix character (normally `'-'`) to introduce optional arguments. But you can change that prefix character.

So a simple trick would be to use an alternate prefix for *sub options*, for example `'/'`.

The command line would be:

```
python3 main.py --make_it source target /option1 itsargs /option2 itsargs moreofitsargs /option3 evenmoreargs /option4 213 andevenmoreags
```

I assume that after initial parsing you have (more or less):

```
make_it_args = ['source', 'target', '/option1', 'itsargs', '/option2', 'itsargs', 'moreofitsargs', '/option3', 'evenmoreargs', '/option4', '213', 'andevenmoreag']

make_it_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='/')
make_it_parser .add_argument('source')
make_it_parser .add_argument('target')
for i in range(1,5):
    make_it_parser ='/option'+str(i)
    make_it_parser .add_argument(name, nargs='*')   # accept any number of arguments including none
```

And you could use it to parse this:

```
make_it_ns = make_it_parser .parse_args(make_it_args )
```

giving for make_it_ns:

```
Namespace(option1=['itsargs'], option2=['itsargs', 'moreofitsargs'], option3=['evenmoreargs'],
          option4=['213', 'andevenmoreag'], source='source', target='target')
```

As usual, a non present option will have `None` as value, and an option with no additionsal argument will receive an empty list (`[]`)

Comment: The idea is: --make_it is only one of the 10 flags in my program, not the root of it. And I want to have --make_it having it's options.

Comment: @Mark: Looks like I had missed an important point :-( It should be more relevant now.